# How to convert ISO-8859-1encoded string into UTF-8 in Objective C

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know How to convert ISO-8859-1 encoded string into UTF-8 string or into NSString in Objective C ?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you have your ISO-8859-1 encoded string in a varaible `isoString` of type `const char*`, then you can create an NSString instance like this:

```
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc]
    initWithCString: isoString encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

Note: Latin-1 and ISO-8859-1 encoding are the same.

With the following code, you can convert it to a UTF-8 encoded C string if needed:

```
const char* utf8String = [str UTF8String];
```

Comment: Thanks For the quick reply. But the i am getting the ISO-8859-1 data as a value of AVMetadataItem. So please suggest for this.

Answer (score 3):

Or in one line:

```
NSString yourFinalString = [NSString stringWithCString:[yourOriginalString cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```